# ThreeJs animate loses context in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js

I want to use ThreeJs in angular 2. I can get the scene and a simple cube to render, but the issue comes when the animate() call is used. Here is the code.

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';

const THREE = require('three');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-threejsscene',
  templateUrl: 'threejsscene.component.html'
})
export class ThreeJsSceneComponent implements OnInit {

  scene: THREE.Scene;
  renderer: THREE.Renderer;
  mesh: any;
  camera: THREE.Camera;
  geometry: THREE.Geometry;
  material: THREE.Material;


  ngOnInit() {

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    this.camera.position.z = 1000;

    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );

    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
    this.scene.add( this.mesh );

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    document.body.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
    this.animate();
  }

  protected animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( this.animate );

    this.mesh.rotation.x += 1;
    this.mesh.rotation.y += 1;

    this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );

  }
}
```

So when this.animate() is called inside of the ngOnInit() it renders the scene (and applies the rotation once). But then when the requestAnimationFrame is called, I get the error that "this" is undefined. So it seems like the context of "this" referring to the class is lost.

So my question: Is there proper/best way to maintain the context of "this" or is there another way to run the animation loop?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Figured out a solution. May not be the cleanest, and will change the answer if someone has a better one. I added in a field to the class call animateCallBack and use this code inside of the ngOnInit instead of the "this.animate()" like before.

```
this.animateCallback = {
      callAnimate: (this.animate).bind(this)
    };
    this.animateCallback.callAnimate();
```

And the animate function is changed to:

```
protected animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( this.animateCallback.callAnimate );

    this.mesh.rotation.x += 1;
    this.mesh.rotation.y += 1;

    this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`/**
      * For a given function, creates a bound function that has the same body as the original function.
      * The this object of the bound function is associated with the specified object, and has the specified initial parameters.
      * @param thisArg An object to which the this keyword can refer inside the new function.
      * @param argArray A list of arguments to be passed to the new function.
      */
    bind(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any;`

Using this my update functions ends up looking something like:

`update () {
    // Schedule the next frame.
    requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    // Draw!
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }`